# Folium Heat Maps

Tags: python, web-mapping, heat-map, folium

I am trying to replicate the following heatmap from this [link](https://alcidanalytics.com/p/geographic-heatmap-in-python).
Seems simple, but my html output is just a tile map with none of the data I'm trying to represent.

Here's what my csv data looks like `for_map`:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
from folium import FeatureGroup, LayerControl, Map, Marker
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

for_map = pd.read_csv('ny_tickets_coord.csv', sep=';')

hmap = folium.Map(location=ny_coord, zoom_start=12)


hm_wide = HeatMap( zip(for_map.Y.values, for_map.X.values),
                     min_opacity=0.2,
                     radius=17, blur=15,
                     max_zoom=1
                 )
hmap.add_child(hm_wide)
hmap.save('heatmap.html')
```

Any ideas as to why my data is not showing up in the map?

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the thread necromancy, but after having had to Google this for the Nth time, I wanted to go ahead and record here that the only thing wrong with the OP's code here is that `HeatMap` wants a **list**, not an iterator.  It should be:

```
hm_wide = HeatMap( list(zip(for_map.Y.values, for_map.X.values)),
                     min_opacity=0.2,
                     radius=17, blur=15,
                     max_zoom=1 
                 )
```

Comment: It's ok. In fact, there is a [necromancer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge for that very purpose :)